# MySQL select where the MOST RECENT date is NOT between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, select

I'm trying to run a query to retrieve customers whose most recent activity is not between +/- 30 days.  For the life of me I can't figure it out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Activity.date NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY'
```

Problem is that I need to make sure that the Activity.created_on field is the MOST RECENT.  I'm not sure how to go about this.  I'm also joining it with the customers table based on customer_id, if that matters.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can select `MAX(Activity.created_on)` for the satisfying rows by grouping on the `custoner_id`.

Comment: @user2989408 Thanks for the comment.  I'll try it.  If it doesn't work, I'll probably end up posting the entire query in the OP lol.

Answer (score 1):

I've a similar table structure and this works for me:

```
select c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name,  max(a.activity_date) date from activities a join clients c on c.id = a.client_id
where a.activity_date
not between  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
group by c.id  
order by date desc, c.first_name, c,last_name
```